# Comment flag popup is hidden when flag from the negative voted answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, comment-flags

There is a strange display issue with the comment flag popup.

When I open a [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/9683469) from the Data Explorer, the comment appeared in the top of the page. Then I click the <kbd>flag</kbd> link, the popup box is appeared but overlapped with the **Answer** box.

This strange issue occurs when the comment's answer have the negative points and it it was ordered by the votes (meant the last answer of the post).

But I can manually click the partial visible part of the popup to flag the comment.

The same is in the below GIF format:

[image: GIF for the issue]

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Henders: It happens in FireFox, Chrome in Windows 8

Comment: I can't repro exactly what you show in the screenshot (Chrome, Windows 7), but I do still see a bug. You show the comment pop-up as disappearing behind the answer box. Mine doesn't disappear (it stays on top like it should), but it *is* partially transparent. (Edit: Actually, I can repro what you show in the screenshot, but it depends on the exact position to which I have scrolled on the page before clicking the "flag" link. Weird. Probably just a simple zindex and opacity bug, though. Good job on the screen GIF!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in [user3956566's answer over on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284084/comment-flag-popup-is-hidden-when-flag-from-the-negative-voted-answers/284110#284110), the root cause here is partial opacity applied to the children of elements with the `comments` class.

Given the only children that actually *need* opacity are the children of the elements with the `comment-text` class, the simple solution is to just apply the styling to those instead.

With this done, the transparency and answer-form collisions no longer occur.